# How to extract specific frequencies in Discrete Fourier Transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm collecting accelerometer data and interested in extracting frequencies from 1-10 Hz. I'm aware of how to do the FFT but not sure how to extract these frequencies 1Hz, 3Hz and 10Hz. Any pointers?

Comment: how is the result of your FFT represented?

Comment: To begin with, how is the accelerometer data represented?

Comment: Accelerometer data is 3 double values in x,y,z. I get the magnitude and work on it. k=fft(mag(x,y,z)). Then I do s=mag(k). s is an array of double values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the inner product of your data with a complex exponential at the frequency of interest. If $g$ is your data, then just substitute for $f$ the value of the frequency you want (e.g., 1, 3, 10, ...):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t) e^{ -j2\pi f t } dt
$$

Or if discrete:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g[n] e^{-j2\pi n \frac{f}{f_s} },
$$

where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency and $N$ is the number of samples you have.

The DFT (which is what the FFT calculates) implements the above but only over a subset of the frequencies. You could also interpolate the output of the FFT, but it's unnecessary and probably easier to just calculate it directly.